# when i return json result from controller to view it is going to print or display on browser itself

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I am returning to view from controller code is:

```
var result = new { Result = "0", Tab = "1", EMsg = "Please Enter Applicant Relation Name In Kannada" };

return Json(result, "text/plain");
```

And in view, I have to handle like this

```
   var response = JSON.parse(responseText); if (response.Result == '1' && response.Tab == '1'){ alert(response.EMsg);$("#TabCertificateDetails")[0].click();}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: what doesn't work ? did you got any error with your current code ?

Comment: the resulting page just shows,no errors it is going to directly print on browser like { Result = "0", Tab = "1", EMsg = "Please Enter Applicant Relation Name In Kannada" }

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug or error.

So basically your return type of controller is JSONResult.

your controller is something like below

```
public JsonResult getData(){
  //your stuff
  var result = new { Result = "0", Tab = "1", EMsg = "Please Enter Applicant Relation Name In Kannada" };
  return Json(result);
}
```

It will print JSON results in your browser. because the return type is JsonResult.

So ideally in your controller, there should be two methods. And should be something like below

```
public IActionResult GetView(){

   return View("your view name")
}

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult getData(){
  //your stuff
  var result = new { Result = "0", Tab = "1", EMsg = "Please Enter Applicant Relation Name In Kannada" };
  return Json(result);
}
```

Now when the controller calls the view it will return a view. after view rendering, you need to make an ajax call to fetch a JSON result. by default json() method will return you a JSON obj. so you don't need to parse it in UI.
After getting the object you just need to do your stuff;

```
//Js code
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/CONTROLLERNAME/METHODNAME",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        //do your stuff
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        console.log(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Apply_New(string VerifiedType,int FacilityCode)
        {    return View(model);}     [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> Insert_FamilyTreeAttestation(string submitButton, string Btn_toCertificate,string Btn_toPhotoDoc,string Btn_toSubmit, CertificateDetailsModel cmodel, ApplificantsDetailsModel model, FormCollection Objform)
        { var result = new { Result = "0", Tab = "2", EMsg = "Please Select Valid Title" };
                            return Json(result, "text/plain");}   this is going to print on browser...

Comment: @anilawati thats what I am saying your return type is JSONresult